# why we need to push the stack (rbp) before calling an extern C function in assembly on MacOs?

Tags: c, assembly, stack, kernel, nasm

I am new to assembly and I was trying to call an extern function of C within assembly code, I tried to call `strlen` function as shown in the below code:

```
global _my_strlen
section .text
extern _strlen

_my_strlen:               ;rdi register has the address of the string that is passed within the main function
    call    _strlen       ;call strlen which is a C function and pass to it rdi
    ret                   ;the return value of strlen is stored in rax and it will be returned to our main
```

this is my main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     my_strlen(char *str);

int     main()
{
    printf("len = %d\n",my_strlen("this len must be 19"));
    return (0);
}
```

however when I compile and run it with nasm, it gives me a segmentation fault as shown below :

```
[1]    58770 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

I searched a little bit, and I found that you should push the stack before calling an extern function and pop it later, so I changed the code like this:

```
global _my_strlen
section .text
extern _strlen

_my_strlen:
    push    rbp            ;Push stack
    call    _strlen        ;call strlen which is a C function and pass to it rdi
    pop     rbp            ;Pop stack
    ret                    ;the return value of strlen is stored in rax and it will be
```

and it worked perfectly as shown in the result:

```
len = 19
```

I don't know why we need to push the stack, and why it segfaults if you didn't so, what's happening in the background and what has got changed after calling `strlen`, does calling `strlen` affect the stack and how?!

Btw I tried to push other registers instead of `rbp` for example `push rdx` `pop rdx` and it worked, and this is making me more confused than before, hope you explain it in a good way, and thanks in advance.

Comment: OS X uses the System V AMD64 ABI. It requires that the stack be aligned at a 16-byte boundary on call. You may want to modify your question given that fact that it can be other registers than `rbp`. Also, a note on terminology, `rbp` is not "the stack". It's typically a pointer to some location in the stack, from which stack-based parameters and local variables have a known offset. The stack is an area in memory.

Comment: I still miss where the argument (string) is either placed in a register or is pushed onto the stack.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie : In 64-bit code (AMD64 System V ABI) it will be in the register `%rdi`. `%rdi` will be set by the caller of `_my_strlen` and then passed down to the _C_ library `_strlen`